# Sets with measure zero are closed under countable unions

Tags: measure-theory

> If $(X,\chi,\mu)$ is a measure space and $Z = \{ E \in \chi \mid \mu(E)=0 \}$ then $Z$ is closed under countable union.

In the other parts to this question, I showed that given any $E \in \chi$ and $F \in Z$ that $E \cap F \in Z$ which followed from $E \cap F \subseteq E$. We also showed that this $Z$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

By previously shown theorems if we have an increasing sequence $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ then the measure of the union of the $E_n$'s is the limit of $\mu(E_n)$ and if the sequence is decreasing with $\mu(E_1) \neq +\infty$ then the measure of the intersection of the $E_n$'s is the limit of $\mu(E_n)$. I have been trying to attack this by cases but I am kind of having trouble distinguishing exactly what cases I have left.

I know if it eventually becomes increasing or decreasing I will be done as the limit will be $0$ or if the sequences are pairwise disjoint, then it is just the sum of the measures which is $0$. I suspect that there is something I can maybe do like rewrite the sequence as the difference of sets and then maybe use $\mu(X \setminus A) = \mu(X)-\mu(A)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\cup_{i=1}^\infty E_i = \cup_{i=1}^\infty\cup_{m=1}^n E_m$ can always be written as an increasing union. As you remarked, the result then follows immediately if you have the result for finite unions.

Alternatively, you could also write $\cup_{i=1}^\infty E_i = \cup_{i=1}^\infty (E_i \setminus (\cup_{m=1}^{i-1} E_m))$ is a disjoint union, where each element is a subset of $E_i$ and hence has measure zero.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you've proven that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(F_n) = \mu(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N} F_n)$, for $F_n \subseteq F_{n+1}$, then just set $F_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_n$.

Since $\{ E_n \}$ are all nullsets, finite unions are nullsets (see below), so $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty } \mu(F_n) = 0$.

Finite unions are nullsets because $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - \mu(A \cap B) = 0$ (and then apply induction as necessary).

Comment: Thank you. I haven't seen the union identity in this course but I do remember it from a probability course. I appreciate it!